# Node Buffers, from utf8 to binary

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, buffer

I'm receiving data as `utf8` from a source and this data was originally in binary form (it was a `Buffer`). I have to convert back this data to a `Buffer`. I'm having a hard time figuring how to do this.

Here's a small sample that shows my problem:

```
var hexString = 'e61b08020304e61c09020304e61d0a020304e61e65';
var buffer1 = new Buffer(hexString, 'hex');

var str = buffer1.toString('utf8');
var buffer2 = new Buffer(str, 'utf8');

console.log('original content:', hexString);
console.log('buffer1 contains:', buffer1.toString('hex'));
console.log('buffer2 contains:', buffer2.toString('hex'));
```

prints

```
original content: e61b08020304e61c09020304e61d0a020304e61e65
buffer1 contains: e61b08020304e61c09020304e61d0a020304e61e65
buffer2 contains: efbfbd1b08020304efbfbd1c09020304efbfbd1d0a020304efbfbd1e65
```

Here, I would like `buffer2` to be the exact same thing as `buffer1`.

How can I convert an `utf8` string to its original binary `Buffer`?

Comment: Avoid hex, try using base64.encode() at source, then base64.decode() at node.js. Eg: "æ" is U+00e6 (unicode) but reads "195 166" (utf8).

Comment: `new Buffer()` is deprecated. These are class methods now, see the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

Comment: where is the doc about utf-8 ? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot expect binary data converted to utf8 and back again to be the same as the original binary data because of the way utf8 works (especially when invalid utf8 characters are replaced with `\ufffd`).

You have to use another format that correctly preserves the data. This could be 'hex', 'base64', 'binary', or some other binary-safe format provided by a third-party module. Obviously you should probably keep it as a Buffer if you can.

Comment: Yes I read some utf-8 docs and specs and it transforms the stream! Thank you!

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier where is the doc about utf-8 ? Thanks!

Comment: Never use the word "obviously" no battle.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is misleading. Your main problem is that you're dealing with invalid UTF-8. If the data were valid, the conversion would not cause issues.

Specifically, take the first two bytes: `e61b`.

In binary, that's: `11100110`, `00011011`. This is invalid. Take a look at this diagram from the [utf-8 wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

[image]

This says that if a byte starts with `1110`, the next byte must start with two bytes starting with `10` after it. This is not the case here.

Whenever js hits an invalid character, it replaces it with �, the [unicode replacement character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FFFD). The codepoint for that is U+FFFD, and the utf-8 encoding of that code point is `efbfbd`. Notice that this shows up in your output a few times.