# Convert a buffer to string and then convert string back to buffer in javascript

Tags: node.js, string, compression, buffer, zlib

I am using ZLIB in NODEJS to compress a string. On compressing the string I get a BUFFER. I want to send that buffer as a PUT request, but the PUT request rejects the BUFFER as it needs only STRING. I am not able to convert BUFFER to STRING and then on the receiving end I cannot decompress that string, so I can get the original data. I am not sure how I can convert the buffer to string and then convert that string to buffer and then decompress the buffer to get the original string.

```
let zlib = require('zlib');
// compressing 'str' and getting the result converted to string
let compressedString = zlib.deflateSync(JSON.stringify(str)).toString();

//decompressing the compressedString
let decompressedString = zlib.inflateSync(compressedString);
```

The last line is causing an issue saying the input is invalid.

I tried to converted the the 'compressedString' to a buffer and then decompress it then also it does not help.

```
//converting string to buffer
let bufferedString = Buffer.from(compressedString, 'utf8');
//decompressing the buffer
//decompressedBufferString = zlib.inflateSync(bufferedString);
```

This code also gives the exception as the input is not valid.

Comment: What have you tried and what is the code that you have now? We will need a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help your specific problem.

Comment: @RickyM I have updated the question. Can you suggest me some solution or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I would read the documentation for [zlib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlib) but the usage is pretty clear.

```
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var zlib = require('zlib');

// create the buffer first and pass the result to the stream
let input = new Buffer(str);

//start doing the compression by passing the stream to zlib
let compressedString = zlib.deflateSync(input);

// To deflate you will have to do the same thing but passing the 
//compressed object to inflateSync() and chain the toString()
let decompressedString = zlib.deflateSync(compressedString).toString();
```

There are a number of ways to handle streams but this is what you are trying to achieve with the code provided.

Comment: I understand this, but now the compressedString is a buffer. I am using an API, where I cannot send a buffer, I need to send a string. So I need some way where I can convert the buffer to a string send it to the API and on the other end where I receive it, I need to convert the string to the buffer and decompress it.

Comment: You will have to include the implemented API code as well so that I can update the answer.

Comment: I am using an internal API, and I won't be able to share that code. The important thing is that it needs a string to be passed to it.

Comment: I keep getting errors when decompressing the string from the initial compression indicating corruption in the data. So far there has been nothing helpful in the process therefore I suggest streaming the buffer to your API instead of passing a string. Otherwise you are better off not compressing the result to send and passing that result to the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RickyM. I think it is not feasible to convert string and buffer back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the buffer as a latin1 string not an utf8 string. For instance if your buffer is in the `mybuf` variable:

```
mybuf.toString('latin1');
```

And send `mybuf` to your API. Then in your frontend code you can do something like this, supposing your response is in the `response` variable:

```
const byteNumbers = new Uint8Array(response.length);
for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = response[i].charCodeAt(0);
}
const blob: Blob = new Blob([byteNumbers], {type: 'application/gzip'});
```

In my experience the transferred size will be *just a little* higher this way compared to sending the buffer, but at least unlike utf8 you can get your original binary data back. I still don't know how to do it with utf8 encoding, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223776/node-buffers-from-utf8-to-binary/25224140#25224140) it doesn't seem possible.