# Decode a utf8 string (image) to buffer/ Image in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, stream, buffer

I'm receiving an image in a stream as shown below that is (`imageBuffer.toString('utf8'))` converted to utf8 string before receiving, however when I try to create a buffer with the following data the buffer appears to be different and not able to recreate image.

msg =   ����ExifII*��DuckyF��,Photoshop 3.08BIM%��Adobed����↵→→→→↵↵↵ ↵↵��g����→!1AQa"q�2��B#��R3ђ��$T���bCSD��%EU�r�cs��!1QA����"a2q�B#���?�65�]����jF(mR�$Pm�*�a��F�H7҄�Ҁ� 7D�(�

console.log( typeOf msg ) => string

So far I have tried this:

```
let buffer = Buffer.from(msg, 'utf8');
let writable = require('fs').createWriteStream( '/home/test.jpg);
writable.write(buffer);
writable.end();
```

Problem is: Not able to reproduce the same image. output buffer size is different from input buffer of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
let buffer = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(msg));
...
```

Comment: msg is a utf8 String. It does not work. buffer.length is 0

Answer (score 0):

Do not send binary as utf-8 string. Try base64:

```
imageBuffer.toString('base64')
```

and:

```
let buffer = Buffer.from(msg, 'base64');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change that code. I receive the file as  "buffer.toString('utf8')" string.

Comment: `You cannot expect binary data converted to utf8 and back again to be the same as the original binary data because of the way utf8 works (especially when invalid utf8 characters are replaced with \ufffd)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25224140/4989460