# Send and receive hex codes over nodejs socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am sending hex code to machine in nodejs socket application and receive hex answer from code below:

```
socket.on('data', function(data){
  console.log('Socket:'+Buffer.from(data).toString('hex'));
});
```

In console I receive this:
0104000100150104125d2befbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd00efbfbdefbfbd

What is expected:

01 04 00 01 00 15 01 04 12 5D 2B FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 80 00 FF FF

I don't understand why there is additional data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems data is string, not buffer.

just try this code

```
const data = Buffer.from('01 04 00 01 00 15 01 04 12 5D 2B FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 80 00 FF FF'.split(' ').map(x => parseInt(x, 16)));
console.log(Buffer.from(data).toString('hex'));
const str = data.toString(); // <- problem!!!
console.log(Buffer.from(str).toString('hex'));
```

You can't send binary buffer directly, just convert to hex string before and to buffer after for example.

Read this topic
[Node Buffers, from utf8 to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223776/node-buffers-from-utf8-to-binary)

Comment: I already had a buffer from socket data. So i had to do data.toString('hex') and this resolved my problem.